# files missing from my PPA package

Tags: ppa

Summary: Uploaded by first attempt at a package to my PPA; after the launchpad build the package, I found that files are missing from the resulting deb package.

My PPA: https://launchpad.net/~graysky/+archive/utils

My package is simply a bash script, config file, init.d scripts/symlinks, and a man page.  Nothing to compile.

How I built it:
Created the dirtree [shown here](http://pastebin.com/eUp3zQ2j) populating the various dirs with the requisite files (i.e. /etc, /usr/bin and so on).  Then did the following:

```
cd ~/ppa-src/profile-sync-daemon-5.16
dh_make --native --copyright GPL --single --email myemail@myserver.com
rm -f debian/*.{ex,EX}

<<<edited debian/control and debian/changelog>>

debuild -S
dput ppa:graysky/utils profile-sync-daemon_5.16_source.changes
```

The files were transferred to launchpad.  After launchpad built the package, I extracted the .deb and found that only the /usr dir was included.  What am I missing?